# Menú de usuario principal (diseño)

Tags: android, menú

Deseo crear un menú de inicio, la verdad busco ideas para poder organizar o diseñar un menú en la `Activity` principal (`MainActivity`), tengo varios `ImageButton` que derivan a diversas `Activities` con funciones diferentes. El punto es ¿Qué menú puedo implementar?
**NOTA**: no deseo usar `Tabs` ni `NavigationDrawer`. ¿Alguna idea? desde ya gracias !

Comment: Hola Felix, de momento los temas de UX no entran en la [tematica del sitio](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/190/2027)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no entra en la tematica del sitio

Comment: Claro, error mio !

Comment: sigue la pauta de diseño que ofrece google en Material Design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas usando ImageButton, podrías diseñar tu menú de la siguiente manera.
Aunque lo correcto es utilizar los patrones de diseño de Android para los menús.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo:

```
<TableLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/ivInvite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias, me has dado una idea !

Comment: ??? y como se implementaría el menú de la imagen. Eso sería de ayuda a los usuarios.

Comment: Hola @Elenasys agregue mi código de ejemplo, aunque existen muchas maneras en las que el OP puede desarrollarla, es cuestión de gustos y necesidades, Saludos. =)

Comment: no veo el código solo un layout =|

Comment: jaja cierto layout de ejemplo